# In the descriptions of monster action options, what's the difference between "one target" and "one creature"?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, targeting

Something I have been wondering about since I started DM'ing: in the Monster Manual, most actions specify "one target", while some have "one creature".

Example with [Ghouls](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/ghoul) & [Ghasts](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/ghast): ***Bite*** specifies one creature, ***Claws*** specify one target.

What is the difference? Does it matter for regular play?

Comment: +1, Nice find. Welcome to the stack. We look forward to your next questions (and answers too!)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

A target includes: creatures, objects, and locations.

The [PHB p194](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/combat#MakinganAttack) states:

> Pick a target ...: a creature, an object or a location.

For spells, [PHB p204](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/spellcasting#Targets) states:

> A spell's description tells you whether the spell targets creatures, objects, or a point of origin...

The Ghoul can use its **Bite** Action to target only other creatures, e.g. PCs, NPCs, beasts and other monsters. It cannot use the **Bite** action to target an object, e.g. a door.

The Ghoul can use its **Claws** Action to target a creature or an object. For example, to do damage to a door.

Comment: The ghoul can, in a 10 wide by 10 tall long corridor, bite a 10x10 gelatinous cube whose corners are not reachable, but it cannot bite the door (unless it is a mimic... good for detecting mimics). Oh, 5e, what realism. Lolz. +1'd

Comment: @davidrice From the makers of "Magic the Lawyering..."

Comment: @Mindwin It can still probably bite the door (and a real treasure chest), it just can't do so as an attack in RAW... now I have the image of a random ghoul just curiously gnawing on everything around it to see if it should scratch it or bite it harder...

Comment: Spells often have similar restrictions. Most can only target creatures while only a few can target objects. For example, fire bolt can target a creature or object while eldritch blast can only target creatures.

Comment: @MrSpudtastic RAW you cannot perform an action on an invalid target, it fails. Mimic or bust. Of course we are not OCD DMs.

Comment: so, the ghoul can use it's claws against itself? for example, if it was under a confusion spell, or if it gained anything from it? (not looking at "claws" perse, but other creatures have other actions with different effects)